# Checking if ActiveRecord find returns a result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to check if a find method returns a result. My find method is the following:

```
post = Post.find(:all, :conditions => { :url => params['url'] }, :limit => 1)
```

What would be a good way to check that `post` contains a result?

Comment: **Rails 3**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682699/check-if-record-exists-from-controller-in-rails/16682728#16682728

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`find :all` returns an empty array (`[]`) if no rows are returned, so you can just use it this way:

```
post = Post.find(:all, :conditions => { :url => params['url'] }, :limit => 1)

unless post.empty?
  # do something...
end
```

By the way, if you do `find :all` you're going to get an array, not a single row. If you're trying to get just one Post, it would be cleaner to use the `find_by` helper or `find :first` or just `first` instead:

```
post = Post.find_by_url params['url']

# or

post = Post.first :conditions => { :url => params['url'] }

# then...

if post
  # do something...
end
```

Comment: One point of interest, if you just use find() with the primary key (not using :all or :first), it raises an exception if nothing was found.

Answer (score 13):

You can try [ActiveRecord::Base.exists?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002268) before

```
Post.exists?(:conditions => { :url => params['url'] })
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the **BANG!** version of the `find_by_url` method to get it to raise an exception of it could not be found and then rescue it later on in that same method/action.

```
def show
  Post.find_by_url!(params[:url])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    flash[:notice] = "The URL you were looking for could not be found."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

If you didn't raise an exception here I believe that Rails would show the *public/404.html* page.

Comment: Plus one for **BANG!**

Answer (score 4):

if post doesn't contain any result it will be an empty list and then:

```
post.empty?
```

will return true.

Answer (score 2):

it may be as simple as changing your finder to:

```
post = Post.find(:first, :conditions => { :url => params['url'] })
```

With this finder, post will either return a single value or nil.  Because nil behaves like false in a condition statement, you can say something like the following:

```
if post
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Post.find_by_id(id_column_value)
```

will return nil rathering than blowing up your program when it can't find a record.

Of course, there's

```
x = Post.where(:any_column_name => value)
```

which always returns an array of results. In which case you could just run an

```
x.each {|t| f(t) }
```

or

```
y = x.map {|t| f(t)}
```

or of course,

```
x[0], x[1], etc
```

Sorry I got a little carried away there

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is checking with [ActiveRecord#any?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-any-3F).