# Check if record exists from controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, exists

In my app a User can create a Business. When they trigger the `index` action in my `BusinessesController` I want to check if a Business is related to the `current_user.id`:

- If yes: display the business.
- If no: redirect to the `new` action.

I was trying to use this:

```
if Business.where(:user_id => current_user.id) == nil
  # no business found
end
```

But it always returns true even when the business doesn't exist...

**How can I test if a record exists in my database?**

Comment: Using `where` will return an empty array if there are no records. And `[]` doesn't equal `nil`

Comment: What about just a `unless Business.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if ActiveRecord find returns a result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866473/checking-if-activerecord-find-returns-a-result)

Answer (score 255, accepted):

**Why your code does not work?**

The `where` method returns an **ActiveRecord::Relation** object (acts like an array which contains the results of the `where`), **it can be empty but it will never be `nil`**.

```
Business.where(id: -1) 
 #=> returns an empty ActiveRecord::Relation ( similar to an array )
Business.where(id: -1).nil? # ( similar to == nil? )
 #=> returns false
Business.where(id: -1).empty? # test if the array is empty ( similar to .blank? )
 #=> returns true
```

---

## How to test if at least one record exists?

**Option 1:** Using [`.exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F)

```
if Business.exists?(user_id: current_user.id)
  # same as Business.where(user_id: current_user.id).exists?
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

---

**Option 2:** Using [`.present?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F) (or [`.blank?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F), the opposite of `.present?`)

```
if Business.where(:user_id => current_user.id).present?
  # less efficiant than using .exists? (see generated SQL for .exists? vs .present?)
else
  # ...
end
```

---

**Option 3:** Variable assignment in the if statement

```
if business = Business.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
  business.do_some_stuff
else
  # do something else
end
```

This option can be considered a code smell by some linters (Rubocop for example).

**Option 3b:** Variable assignment

```
business = Business.where(user_id: current_user.id).first
if business
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

You can also use `.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)` instead of `.where(...).first`

---

**Best option:**

- If you don't use the `Business` object(s): **Option 1**
- If you need to use the `Business` object(s): **Option 3**

Comment: That didn't seem to work. It keeps passing that test and loading the index html like with the == nil test (so I'm getting an error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass).

Comment: Try with first before calling present

Comment: Oh that's my fault I was confuse, you need to test with `blank?`

Comment: Thanks that worked! I shouldn't have noticed that mistake. Could you tell me why the == nil check didn't work?

Comment: Yes give me a minute I will update my answer, also don't use the `.first` before `.blank?` ;)

Comment: I didn't I removed the first. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 30):

In this case I like to use the `exists?` method provided by ActiveRecord:

```rb
Business.exists? user_id: current_user.id
```

Comment: Is exists? with OR possible?

Answer (score 5):

with 'exists?':

```
Business.exists? user_id: current_user.id #=> 1 or nil
```

with 'any?':

```
Business.where(:user_id => current_user.id).any? #=> true or false
```

---

**If you use something with .where, be sure to avoid trouble with scopes and better use
[.unscoped](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped)**

```
Business.unscoped.where(:user_id => current_user.id).any?
```

Comment: Better use Business.unscoped.where(:user_id => current_user.id).pluck(:id).any?  to avoid unnecesary load of relations for the object you are checking.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord#where will return an ActiveRecord::Relation object (which will never be nil). Try using .empty? on the relation to test if it will return any records.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Business.where(:user_id => current_user.id)` you will get an array. This Array may have no objects or one or many objects in it, but it won't be null.  Thus the check == nil will never be true.

You can try the following:

```
if Business.where(:user_id => current_user.id).count == 0
```

So you check the number of elements in the array and compare them to zero.

or you can try:

```
if Business.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).nil?
```

this will return one or nil.

Answer (score 1):

```
business = Business.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
if business.nil?
# no business found
else
# business.ceo = "me"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way if you needed an instance variable of the object to work with:

```
if @business = Business.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
  #Do stuff
else
  #Do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something new to try (:

Assign a variable or return

```
return unless @business = Business.where(user_id: current_user.id).first
```

Method would exit at this point if there are no businesses found with current user's ID, or assigns instance variable `@business` to the first business object.