# Rails checking if a record exists in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, null

What is the most efficient of way of checking if a database will return a record before processing it.  Example: `Truck.where("id = ?", id).select('truck_no').first.truck_no`

This may or may not return a truck if the truck exists.  What is the most efficient way for me to ensure the page will not crash when processing this request.  How would I handle this both in the view and the controller if lets say I was using a loop to go through each truck and print out its number.

If the record does not exist I would like to be able to print out a message instead saying no records found.

Comment: which version of rails are you on?

Comment: Have a look at exists? method http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if record exists from controller in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682699/check-if-record-exists-from-controller-in-rails)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

If you want to check for the existence of an object why not use exists?

```
if Truck.exists?(10)
  # your truck exists in the database
else
  # the truck doesn't exist
end
```

The `exists?` method has the advantage that is not selecting the record from the database (meaning is faster than selecting the record).
The query looks like:

```
SELECT 1 FROM trucks where trucks.id = 10
```

You can find more examples in the [Rails documentation for #exists?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F).

Comment: `exists?` is not limited to primary key of an object only. You can pass a query like this too:  `Person.exists?(['name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%"])`

Answer (score 35):

Here is how you can check this.

```
if Trucks.where(:id => current_truck.id).blank?
  # no truck record for this id
else
  # at least 1 record for this truck
end
```

**where** method returns an **ActiveRecord::Relation object** (acts like an array which contains the results of the where), it can be empty but never be nil.

Comment: I always thought it would return a nil.  Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @whoever just downvoted it. Please add a comment, so it helps understand what's wrong here..

Comment: Use `exists?` insetad of `blank?`. This will perform a query to check if object exists in DB instead of retrieving whole object.

Comment: in ruby on rails any function ending with question mark '?' returns boolean i.e true or false . whether it's `exists?` or `blank?`

Comment: @ImranNaqvi using `blank?` can be much worse since it will return _all_ records before checking if there are any where `exists?` adds `LIMIT 1` to the sql statement so that at most only one record will ever be loaded. See @cristian's answer below.

Answer (score 8):

**OP actual use case solution**

The simplest solution is to combine your DB check and retrieval of data into 1 DB query instead of having separate DB calls.  Your sample code is close and conveys your intent, but it's a little off in your actual syntax.

If you simple do `Truck.where("id = ?", id).select('truck_no').first.truck_no` and this record does NOT exists, it will throw a `nil` error when you call `truck_no` because `first` may retrieve a `nil` record if none are found that match your criteria.

That's because your query will return an array of objects that match your criteria, then you do a `first` on that array which (if no matching records are found) is `nil`.

A fairly clean solution:

```
# Note: using Rails 4 / Ruby 2 syntax
first_truck = Truck.select(:truck_no).find_by(id) # => <Truck id: nil, truck_no: "123"> OR nil if no record matches criteria

if first_truck
  truck_number = first_truck.truck_no
  # do some processing...
else
  # record does not exist with that criteria
end
```

I recommend using clean syntax that "comments" itself so others know exactly what you're trying to do.

If you really want to go the extra mile, you could add a method to your `Truck` class that does this for you and conveys your intent:

```
# truck.rb model
class Truck < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.truck_number_if_exists(record_id)
    record = Truck.select(:truck_no).find_by(record_id)
    if record
      record.truck_no
    else
      nil # explicit nil so other developers know exactly what's going on
    end
  end
end
```

Then you would call it like so:

```
if truck_number = Truck.truck_number_if_exists(id)
  # do processing because record exists and you have the value
else
  # no matching criteria
end
```

The `ActiveRecord.find_by` method will retrieve the first record that matches your criteria or else returns `nil` if no record is found with that criteria.  Note that the order of the `find_by` and `where` methods is important; you must call the `select` on the `Truck` model.  This is because when you call the `where` method you're actually returning an `ActiveRelation` object which is not what you're looking for here.

[See ActiveRecord API for 'find_by' method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

**General solutions using 'exists?' method**

As some of the other contributors have already mentioned, the `exists?` method is engineered specifically to check for the existence of something.  It doesn't return the value, just confirms that the DB has a record that matches some criteria.

It is useful if you need to verify uniqueness or accuracy of some piece of data.  The nice part is that it allows you to use the `ActiveRelation(Record?) where(...)` criteria.

For instance, if you have a `User` model with an `email` attribute and you need to check if an email already exists in the dB:

`User.exists?(email: "test@test.com")`

The benefit of using `exists?` is that the SQL query run is

`SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test@test.com' LIMIT 1`

which is more efficient than actually returning data.

If you need to actually conditionally retrieve data from the DB this isn't the method to use.  However, it works great for simple checking and the syntax is very clear so other developers know exactly what you're doing.  Using appropriate syntax is critical in projects with multiple developers.  Write clean code and let the code "comment" itself.

Comment: In ruby any function returning true or false which is `truck_number_if_exists(id)` in your case , should have question mark in the end

Comment: @ImranNaqvi: you're correct that the convention in Ruby is to append `?` to boolean methods; however, in this case, `truck_number_if_exist(id)` is not a boolean method; it returns a value if one exists otherwise returns nil. Since it is not a boolean method it should not use a `?` at the end.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to check whether the record exists or not. Go with the @cristian's answer i.e.

`Truck.exists?(truck_id) # returns true or false`

But if truck exists and you want to access that truck then you will have to find truck again which will lead to two database queries. If this is the case go with

```
@truck = Truck.find_by(id: truck_id) #returns nil or truck
@truck.nil? #returns true if no truck in db
@truck.present? #returns true if no truck in db
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just do:

```
@truck_no = Truck.where("id = ?", id).pluck(:truck_no).first
```

This will return `nil` if no record is found, or `truck_no` of *only the first* record otherwise.

Then in your view you could just do something like:

```
<%= @truck_no || "There are no truck numbers" %>
```

If you want to fetch and display multiple results, then in your controller:

```
@truck_nos = Truck.where("id = ?", id).pluck(:truck_no)
```

and in your view:

```
<% truck_nos.each do |truck_no| %>
  <%= truck_no %>
<% end %>

<%= "No truck numbers to iterate" if truck_nos.blank? %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I never knew about pluck method.

Comment: You're welcome. `pluck` will select a single column from your table.

Answer (score 1):

Rails has a [`persisted?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted%3F) method
 for using like you want

Comment: `persisted?` has a different purposed. It's used to check an object has been written to database.

Comment: `truck.persisted?` returns true, if the truck has at some point been stored into the database. Even if it after that it has been removed from database.