# Rails - check if a user is persisted by checking if an email address inserted in another form is now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, persisted-column

I have models called User and Invite in my Rails 4 app.

I allow users to invite others to their project teams.

My user model has an attribute called :email.

I have an invite model for this purpose, it has the following attributes:

```
create_table "invites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.string   "token"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "accepted",     default: false
    t.date     "expiry"
```

When a user invites another person to join a project, they fill out a form that collects the above information.

Then in my invites controller, I'm trying to check if the email address entered is already an email address associated with any user's account.

In my Invites Controller, I have:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_project
  before_action :recipient_status_known, only: :create

  def index
    @invites = @project.invites
  end

  def new
    # @invite = Invite.new
    @invite = @project.invites.build
  end

  def create
    @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
    @invite.sender_id = current_user.profile.id

    # @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

    if @invite.save && @recipient_status_known
        @invite.recipient_id = @invite.email.user.id  

        #send existing user email invitation to join project team
        InviteMailer.existing_user_invite(@invite).deliver_later 
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Invitation sent'  }

         #Add the user to the user group - inivte rsvp pending
         @invite.recipient.project.push(@invite.project)
      elsif @invite.save && !@recipient_status_known
        InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite).deliver_later 
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Invitation sent'  }
      else
        #send new user email invitation to join site and this project team
         @invite.recipient.project.push(@invite.project)

         # InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(:invite_token => @invite.token)).deliver
      end

       # oh no, creating an new invitation failed

  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_invite
      @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
    end

    def recipient_status_known
      User.persisted?(email: @invite.email)
    end

    def get_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def invite_params
      params[:invite].permit(:email, :project_id, :recipient_id, :token, :accepted, :expiry, :message)
    end
end
```

The recipient_status_known method is my attempt at checking if the email that is inserted in the new invites form is already in the database on the user table (saved as email).

If it is known, then the create action should assign the known user id as the recipient id on the invite table.

If it is not known, then I want to send the invited person an email inviting them to create an account.

How can I fix my test in the invite controller, to check if the User table has an email address provided in the new invite form?

**My next attempt** is to update my invite controller as follows:

```
after_filter :recipient_status_known, only: :create

def create
      @invite = Invite.new(invite_params)
      @invite.sender_id = current_user.profile.id

if @invite.save && @recipient_status_known
     @invite.recipient_id = @invite.email.user.id   
     InviteMailer.existing_user_invite(@invite).deliver_later 
     format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Invitation sent'  }
     @invite.recipient.project.push(@invite.project)

elsif @invite.save && @recipient_status_known == false
  # InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite).deliver_later 
    format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Invitation sent'  }
else
    format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Something went wrong'  }
end
```

end

My method to check if the email address added to the invite table is the same as any existing user member, is:

```
def recipient_status_known
        User.exists?(email: @invite.email)
    end
```

When I save this and try to submit the new invite form, I get no errors, but I get an error with the redirect in the last line of this code. That means that the email is not being found as a matching 'recipient status known' address. I know the email address that I am entering in the new invite form does match an email address in the user's table.

Any ideas on what I can try next?

Comment: What kind of error did you notice? Also, please check that http://stackoverflow.com/a/16682728/1702557

Comment: The error is: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
- it points to the recipient_status_known method

Comment: Okey, I would try to manually pass `email` as method argument.

Comment: What does that mean? in plain english?

Comment: Edited answer below. Also I noticed that there is `before_action :recipient_status_known, only: :create`. `recipient_status_known` might be called when `create` method is called and `@invite` is not yet populated. What is the reason to have `before_action` defined`?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use something like this

```
def recipient_status_known(email)
    User.exists?(email: email)
end
```

But `recipient_status_known` method is used in `before_action`. It might happen that `recipient_status_known` method is called before `@invite` is set in `create` method.

Proposed change to use argument `email` will cause an error.

Based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16682728/1702557

Comment: so your suggestion differs to my attempt in that you suggest using exists? where I have used persisted?  ? The reason I used persisted is that it excludes existing records that have been deleted. I think part of the problem might be that the method is being called in the invite controller when I am trying to check records in the user table. I'm not sure if that is part of the problem.

Comment: In any event, I tried swapping persisted? for exists? but still get this error, when I know the email address I am typing into the new invite form is an email address in the database: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @Mel, got it, thank you. I updated the answer to use arguments.

Comment: Then I get an error that says: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Comment: It is due to used `before_action` for method `create`. `recipient_status_known` is called when `@invite` is not yet set.

Comment: I changed the before action to an after filter and went back to my original definition. Now, I don't get an error, but I also don't get the email triggered. Something is wrong because the email address I put in the new invite form is already saved in the database as a user email