# How to return true if string exists in table, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I need the controller to check if a string exists in a table and then return "true" or "false" so that I can use it in an if statement.
For example, if the string "Robert" exists in the "my_friends" table, I need to display those corresponding items related to "Robert" from another table called "goodtimes."

I realize the .exists won't work in this application because I'm searching for a string.

```
@my_friends.where(friend_id: 'Robert').exists?   #always returns false
    @goodtimes = goodtime.where friend_id: "Robert" #works
```

The pseudo code would look like this:

```
if (table x contains string "Robert")
    @goodtimes = goodtime.where friend_id: "Robert" #display goodtimes from table y
```

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Comment: You want to search that string in every column of the table?

Comment: No, just the friend_id column.  The friend_id column is in both tables.

Comment: Use your model and do a regular AR query, what is the model of the table you want to query?

Comment: I should have said that I'm new to Rails.  I don't understand your question.  The file in the model directory doesn't contain anything other than the class and then end.  What's an AR query?  Thanks btw for helping.

Comment: AR stands fro ActiveRecord, and that's how rails (by default) queries the database. What have you assigned to `@my_friends`? You probably query the database using something like `MyFriends.where...`; with that you are using AR.

Comment: I get a syntax error.  dynamic constant assignment?

Comment: Can you post the complete block of code your are using?

Comment: OMG, it worked!  Thank you so much.  I've been working on this for days!  I had your response typed incorrectly.

Comment: Glad to help, but if you mean the answer below, that was not me, that's @shambalambala answer. If it worked you can thank him by accepting the answer :)

Comment: Thank you both!  This means so much to me.  You are both good people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether Robert exists or not by using `.where().present`

```
if @my_friends.where(:friend_id => 'Robert').present?
  # Robert exists
else
  # Robert doesn't exist
end
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16682728/7954580) for more ways to check if a record exists.

Comment: Thank you shambalambala!