# Rails callback check if record exists, else return 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm building an app where users can accept bookings from clients via their own booking page. These unique urls will all be public facing (no auth) and sent to potential clients by the user (this is how my client requested the functionality). When I enter an existing user's booking URL (e.g. `https://localhost:3000/users/1/appointments/new`) in the browser, the page works perfectly. When I enter the URL for a user that does not exist (e.g. `https://localhost:3000/users/5999/appointments/new`) I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BookingsController#booking_page 
Couldn't find User with 'id'=100
```

Instead of this error I would like to redirect to the 404 page instead. This is my controller (`redirect_to_not_found` is not being used, I was testing this in a `before_action`):

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :booking_page
  before_action :set_user, only: :booking_page
  layout 'public', only: :booking_page
  def booking_page
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user
        format.html { render :booking_page }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :ok }
      else
        format.html { render(:file => Rails.root.join('public', '404'), :formats => [:html], :status => 404, :layout => false) }
        format.json { render json: 'Not Fount', status: :not_found }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def redirect_to_not_found
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user == nil
        format.html { render(:file => Rails.root.join('public', '404'), :formats => [:html], :status => 404, :layout => false) }
        format.json { render json: 'Not Fount', status: :not_found }
      end
    end
  end

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def bookings_params
    params.require(:user_booking).permit(:client_firstname, :client_surname, :client_email, :client_mobile_namber, :services_required, :notes, :date, :start_time, :end_time, :location, :cost, :payment_completed)
  end
end
```

Is there any way I can assign set the `@user` variable/object before running the `booking_page` action method and check if the user exists in the database at the same time?

I tried using the accepted answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682699/check-if-record-exists-from-controller-in-rails) but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`User.find`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) raises error when record is not in the DB. You can use nil-flavour of finders, e.g. [find_by](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

```
@user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

It will set `@user` to `nil` if it's not in the DB

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your controller to rescue from this error/exception. You can put it in your `ApplicationController` for app-wide effect or in specific controllers.

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
  logger.error "Not found ..."
  redirect_to 404_path  # You will have to configure this yourself in routes.rb
  # ... OR use your method
  redirect_to_not_found
end
```